# FTPS connection using SSL

Tags: .net, powershell, ftps

I'm trying to switch my FTP calls to FTPS on PowerShell to make them more secure. I currently use the WebRequest library to do my FTP calls and found that there's an EnableSsl method that you can set to true to use SSL. I'm not sure if it's the proper way to set the FTP connection to FTPS, but I'm also trying to verify the certificate information before connecting.

Is there a way to do so? Code snippit example below:

```
$request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
if ($credentials) { $request.Credentials = $credentials }
$request.UsePassive = $true
$request.EnableSsl = $true;
$response = $request.GetResponse()
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream() 
$reader.ReadToEnd()
$reader.Close()
$response.Close()
```

Comment: As for this --- I'm also trying to verify the certificate information before connecting. --- Do you control this FTP site, or is it 3rdP controlled?

Comment: You can follow the C# example, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adarshk/2005/04/22/using-ftpwebrequest-to-do-ftp-over-ssl/ but accordingly to sites such as https://ftps.codeplex.com the .NET Framework built-in classes have limitations that might prevent you from connecting to some FTPS setup.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through my library, here is a function I have and use in my lab that may work for your efforts. 
I have no FTP servers to test against, but this works against remote SSL targets - internal and external

```
Function Request-CertificateDetails
{
    [CmdletBinding()]

    [Alias('rcd')]

    Param
    (
        [string[]]$Destination = (Read-Host 'Enter a NetBIOS name, FQDN or URL to the host'),
        [string]$Port = '443',
        [switch]$CertificateChain
    )

    $WebRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::CreateHttp("https://$($Destination):$Port")
    $WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = $true
    $chain = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}

    #Request website
    try {$Response = $WebRequest.GetResponse()}
    catch {}

    #Creates Certificate
    $Certificate = $WebRequest.ServicePoint.Certificate.Handle
    $Issuer = $WebRequest.ServicePoint.Certificate.Issuer
    $Subject = $WebRequest.ServicePoint.Certificate.Subject

    #Build chain
    $chain.Build($Certificate)
    $chain.ChainElements.Count #This returns "1" meaning none of the CA certs are included.
    $chain.ChainElements[0].Certificate.IssuerName.Name

    [Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = $null

    If($CertificateChain)
    {
        $chain.ChainElements.Certificate
        $chain.ChainElements.Certificate | Select-Object *
    }
}

# Is the cert available and valid
Request-CertificateDetails -Destination 'stackoverflow.com' -Port 443


#Results

True
3
CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US


# Is the cert available and valid and list the cert chain
Request-CertificateDetails -Destination 'stackoverflow.com' -Port 443 -CertificateChain


# Results


True
3
CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US

Thumbprint                                Subject                                                                                                                       
----------                                -------                                                                                                                       
47ADB03649A2EB18F63FFA29790818349A99CAB7  CN=*.stackexchange.com, O="Stack Exchange, Inc.", L=New York, S=NY, C=US                                                      
A031C46782E6E6C662C2C87C76DA9AA62CCABD8E  CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US                                          
5FB7EE0633E259DBAD0C4C9AE6D38F1A61C7DC25  CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US                                              

EnhancedKeyUsageList : {Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1), Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)}
DnsNameList          : {*.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, *.stackoverflow.com, stackauth.com...}
SendAsTrustedIssuer  : False
Archived             : False
Extensions           : {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid...}
FriendlyName         : 
IssuerName           : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
NotAfter             : Wed 14 Aug 02019 05:00:00
NotBefore            : Fri 20 May 02016 17:00:00
HasPrivateKey        : False
PrivateKey           : 
PublicKey            : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey
RawData              : {48, 130, 7, 30...}
SerialNumber         : 0E11BBD70D54B710D0C6F540B6B52CA4
SubjectName          : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
SignatureAlgorithm   : System.Security.Cryptography.Oid
Thumbprint           : 47ADB03649A2EB18F63FFA29790818349A99CAB7
Version              : 3
Handle               : 1932723065648
Issuer               : CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Subject              : CN=*.stackexchange.com, O="Stack Exchange, Inc.", L=New York, S=NY, C=US


EnhancedKeyUsageList : {Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1), Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)}
DnsNameList          : {DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA}
SendAsTrustedIssuer  : False
Archived             : False
Extensions           : {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid...}
FriendlyName         : 
IssuerName           : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
NotAfter             : Sun 22 Oct 02028 05:00:00
NotBefore            : Tue 22 Oct 02013 05:00:00
HasPrivateKey        : False
PrivateKey           : 
PublicKey            : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey
RawData              : {48, 130, 4, 177...}
SerialNumber         : 04E1E7A4DC5CF2F36DC02B42B85D159F
SubjectName          : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
SignatureAlgorithm   : System.Security.Cryptography.Oid
Thumbprint           : A031C46782E6E6C662C2C87C76DA9AA62CCABD8E
Version              : 3
Handle               : 1932723063856
Issuer               : CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Subject              : CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US


EnhancedKeyUsageList : {Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1), Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2), Secure Email (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4), Code Signing 
                       (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3)...}
DnsNameList          : {DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA}
SendAsTrustedIssuer  : False
Archived             : False
Extensions           : {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid}
FriendlyName         : DigiCert
IssuerName           : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
NotAfter             : Sun 09 Nov 02031 16:00:00
NotBefore            : Thu 09 Nov 02006 16:00:00
HasPrivateKey        : False
PrivateKey           : 
PublicKey            : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey
RawData              : {48, 130, 3, 197...}
SerialNumber         : 02AC5C266A0B409B8F0B79F2AE462577
SubjectName          : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
SignatureAlgorithm   : System.Security.Cryptography.Oid
Thumbprint           : 5FB7EE0633E259DBAD0C4C9AE6D38F1A61C7DC25
Version              : 3
Handle               : 1932723062704
Issuer               : CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Subject              : CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
```